# How to Make Eclipse (C++) Switch from/to Debug Perspective Automatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How do you make Eclipse CDT **automatically** switch to the Debug perspective when I begin debugging, and **automatically switch back to the previous perspective** when the debuggees have terminated?

**Note:** In case this wasn't clear: I'm looking for a solution for switching to Debug ***and back***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Perspective Switcher](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/indexa36f.html?entry=1758AACF-910C-DE52-368E1421BEFDA19B) has a configurable feature to automatically switch back to the previous perspective when the debugger terminates.  It can also be configured to automatically switch to any perspective based on file extensions you specify.  When an editor gets activated (i.e. opening a file or switching to a different file), then the perspective is automatically changed.  This makes it easy to work with multiple languages.

Comment: It seems partly buggy (when I enter `.h .hpp .c .cpp` under C/C++ and I enter `.htm .html` under Web, it starts switching to Web for `.h` files) but it still seems to get the job done otherwise, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I've been after this myself (as it would be very convenient) every now and again, but so far in my search I've come up with nothing.

Short of writing an Eclipse plugin to switch to previous perspective on debugger disconnect there is no "automatic" solution.

However, I have grown accustomed to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> which is default shortcut (on Windows) to switch back to "Previous Perspective".

Comment: Ugh, so there's no built-in way? At least glad to know I'm not the only one missing this... (It's really tempting for me to go on a rant here about this but I'll try and avoid it. :P) +1 thanks for confirming.

Answer (score -2):

When you manually switch to Debug mode for the first time while debugging it will show a checkbox with 'Automatically  switch to Debug in future'.

Comment: You missed the crucial other half of the question.